# Maintain unchanged checkbox with AJAX call error with Vuejs and VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have one component with a list of users that I get from Vuex:

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters(['users'])
}
```

In my html template I have:

```
<li v-for="user in users">
    <b-form-checkbox :checked="userIsActive(user)" @change="toggleActiveUser(user)"></b-form-checkbox>
</li>
```

And in My methods:

```
userIsActive(user) {
   return user.active;
},
toggleActiveUser(user) {
   this.$store.dispatch("setState", user);
},
```

in the dispatch I make a ajax call like:

```
return Vue.axios.post(url).then((response)=>{
   commit("UPDATE_USER_IN_USERS", response.data.user);
}).catch((err)=>{
   console.log(err);
});
```

on commit I will change my user in users state, and it works, if I print state of "user" in list, it changes correctly or not changes if there is an error on ajax call.

But my problem is when the ajax call return error.

The Checkbox **change** every time, even if there is an error on ajax call and so when I don't change my vuex state.

I can't use simple v-model with Vuex strict.

So How I can mantain uncheck or checked checkbox when the ajax call return error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the user has already manually checked/unchecked the checkbox, so when your ajax call returns with an error, you are just not updating your vuex state to match the manually checked box.

When your ajax returns with an error, you can use javascript to find the checkbox manually check/uncheck it again. This will probably require setting a unique id on each checkbox. Something like this:

```
setState: function(context, user) {
  return Vue.axios.post(url).then((response)=>{
     commit("UPDATE_USER_IN_USERS", response.data.user);
  }).catch((err)=>{
     document.getElementById(user.id).checked = user.active;
  });
}
```

Comment: It Makes sense. Thank you!